Reusable Radio widget in flutter
I'm a noob when it comes to flutter and I am trying to create a re-usable Radio widget (Male or Female) where I use it twice and pass gender as its parameter as an Enum. The issue I am facing is both the radios can get selected instead of one. Please help me out
class RadioButton extends StatefulWidget {
  RadioButton({super.key, required this.gender});
  final GenderEnum gender;
  

  @override
  State<RadioButton> createState() => _RadioButtonState();
}


class _RadioButtonState extends State<RadioButton> {
  GenderEnum? _genderEnum;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      Radio(
          value: widget.gender,
          groupValue: _genderEnum,
          onChanged: (value)
          {
            setState(() {
              _genderEnum = value;
            });
          }),
      Text(widget.gender.name.toString()),
    ]);
  }
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 400,
            right: 400,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Enter your Employee ID",
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                      left: Radius.circular(16),
                      right: Radius.circular(16),
                    ))),
                controller: _empid,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return "Please enter your EmpID";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              TextField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      hintText: "Enter your Team Name",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                        left: Radius.circular(16),
                        right: Radius.circular(16),
                      ))),
                  controller: _empteam),
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  RadioButton(gender: GenderEnum.Male),
                  RadioButton(gender: GenderEnum.Female),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

I know the code must be mildly infuriating for experienced flutter developers but I have been scratching my head since an embarrassingly long time for a simple (not so simple) Radio button
.

Maybe You Are Looking For This: How to select only one group value of radio button in Flutter (stackoverflow radio button flutter)

Here is reusable class:

class RadioButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const RadioButton({
    super.key,
    required this.gender,
    required this.groupValue,
    required this.onChanged,
  });

  final GenderEnum gender;
  final GenderEnum? groupValue;
  final ValueChanged<GenderEnum?> onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Radio<GenderEnum>(
          value: gender,
          groupValue: groupValue,
          onChanged: onChanged,
        ),
        Text(gender.name.toString()),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Use this class :
RadioButton(
       gender: GenderEnum.Male or GenderEnum.Female,
       groupValue: _genderEnum,
       onChanged: (GenderEnum? value) {
       setState(() {
               _selectedGender = value;
       });
   },
),

